# Cross Join Creating duplicates, triplicates and so on in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing Archival of Data from 1 schema to another schema on same server.
I have Day0 table(all basic information is maintain in this table) which has Source_tableName, Dest_TableName, Date_Column(on which Archival will be running), Retention_Period columns and also Custom_Query column where I can Join some data of table.

Right now I am working on 1 table which has this custom_query column and its Join is creating
multiple records in Destination table.

Case1:Tried Below scenario:

```
Insert into Dest_Table 
SELECT a.* FROM Source_Table  a, dual 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT distinct file_id FROM File_table b 
WHERE  a.fileid=b.cod_file_id  AND  TRUNC(DAT_UPLOAD) < '01-Jan-2018' );
```

But I want to close brackets of after first condition only since remaining "`AND TRUNC(FILE_UPLOAD)`" I am taking from Day0 table at runtime in code by calling package. But DAT_UPLOAD column is from File_Table due to which I ma getting `ORA-00904: "DAT_UPLOAD"`: invalid identifier.
Please help me to re-write query properly. Instead of Dual can I use "File_table"?
Please note below query tried to resolve Case2 but its creating issue due to closing backet.
Query:

```
Insert into Dest_Table 
SELECT a.* FROM Source_Table  a, dual 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT distinct file_id FROM File_table b 
WHERE  a.fileid=b.cod_file_id**)** AND  TRUNC(DAT_UPLOAD) < '01-Jan-2018';
```

Case2: Below query created duplicates.
Query:

```
Insert into Dest_Table 
SELECT a.* FROM  Source_Table a, File_table b 
WHERE   a.fileid=b.cod_file_id AND TRUNC(DAT_UPLOAD) < '01-Jan-2018';
```

since "File_table" has 2 or more rows for for cod_file_id and Source_Table has 1 row but I only wanted to validate data with File_table and Insert it then to Dest_table.

Hopefully I clearly mentioned my doubt.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of DUAL table in your queries? If DAT_UPLOAD is DATE, why are you comparing it to a string? I don't see any error in closing bracket (the one you marked with asterisks). If DAT_UPLOAD belongs to FILE_TABLE, you can't reference it outside of a subquery (which selects from that table). Perhaps you should post several sample records which illustrate what you have, as well as target table (and desired result) so that we'd be able to reproduce what you're doing.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: If your purpose is to select rows from the source_table which have at least one corresponding row in the file_table that has a dat_upload before 2018, then your first query (with a couple of tweaks - remove the dual table; it serves no purpose and, assuming dat_upload is of DATE format, convert the `'01-Jan-2018'` string to a date, e.g. `to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`) would do the trick. If you're after something else, please explain (with sample input and expected output data) exactly what you're trying to do. Also, what columns are in the dest_table? is it just the source_table cols?

Comment: Why AND TRUNC(DAT_UPLOAD) < '01-Jan-2018'? Simply DAT_UPLOAD < date '2018-01-01' should be enough and even more efficient. Or, if you must include also 2018-01-01, then DAT_UPLOAD < date '2018-01-02' should do. For better performance avoid applying trunc to the column.

Answer (score 0):

A cross join to dual would not increase the number of rows because dual has 1 row (any integer multiplied by 1 = the original integer). So your assumption about that cross join seems wrong, plus there is no point in the cross join to dual anyway.

When using EXISTS, the sub-query select clause really has no effect, so there is no need to use `select distinct file_id` this will not make your query more efficient. It is really only the from & where clauses that are important in EXISTS because they do the testing for existence of any rows that match. So you can use `select null` or `select 1` or `select *` and you would not alter the outcome or performance of the overall query.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Source_Table a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 -- I prefer select null, but the choice is just a personal preference here
        FROM File_table b
        WHERE a.fileid = b.cod_file_id
            AND b.DAT_UPLOAD < date '2018-01-01' -- assumes DAT_UPLOAD is from b and is date or timestamp
        );
```

It isn't clear to me what you mean by "*But I want to close brackets of after first condition*", if the DAT_UPLOAD is in source_table (alias a) then do this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Source_Table a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 -- I prefer select null, you can use select * if you prefer
        FROM File_table b
        WHERE a.fileid = b.cod_file_id
        )
 AND a.DAT_UPLOAD < date '2018-01-01' -- assumes DAT_UPLOAD is from a and is date or timestamp
```

As observed in comment under the question there should be no need to use TRUNC() in your query, but IF you also need to include date/time values such as `2018-01-01 15:42:56` into the result, then I suggest you just move you filter date to `date '2018-01-02'`

Also note that when using EXISTS it also will not multiply the result set of your query. So, the cross join to dual doesn't multiply the rows and neither does using EXISTS then that only leaves Source_Table for the "duplicates or triplicates". Perhaps you haven't supplied the complete query and there are other tables being joined? If so then it is almost certainly those joins that multiply your rows.